# What is difference between these two slicing in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array

```
X=array([[0, 44.0, 72000.0],
   [2, 27.0, 48000.0],
   [1, 30.0, 54000.0],
   [2, 38.0, 61000.0],
   [1, 40.0, 63777.0],
   [0, 35.0, 58000.0],
   [2, 38.0, 52000.0],
   [0, 48.0, 79000.0],
   [1, 50.0, 83000.0],
   [0, 37.0, 67000.0]], dtype=object)
```

I want to extract whole 3rd column and I sliced like this `X[:,2:3]` but it was not scikit learn fit_transform function gives an error on this  but when I sliced like this `X[:,2]` it worked fine.
`X[:,2:3]` give output

```
array([[72000.0],
       [48000.0],
       [54000.0],
       [61000.0],
       [63777.77777777778],
       [58000.0],
       [52000.0],
       [79000.0],
       [83000.0],
       [67000.0]], dtype=object)
```

and `X[:,2]` give output

```
array([72000.0, 48000.0, 54000.0, 61000.0, 63777.77777777778, 58000.0,
       52000.0, 79000.0, 83000.0, 67000.0], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Why not print the output from both and see what they give you.

Comment: the [shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) is different. you might want to use the `.reshape` function

Comment: One is a 2D matrix with one column, the other is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the shape of the array:

Code

```
from numpy import *

X=array([[0, 44.0, 72000.0],
         [2, 27.0, 48000.0],
         [1, 30.0, 54000.0],
         [2, 38.0, 61000.0],
         [1, 40.0, 63777.0],
         [0, 35.0, 58000.0],
         [2, 38.0, 52000.0],
         [0, 48.0, 79000.0],
         [1, 50.0, 83000.0],
         [0, 37.0, 67000.0]], dtype=object)

X1 = X[:,2:3]
X2 = X[:,2]

print(X1.shape)
print(X2.shape)
```

Result:

```
(10L, 1L)

(10L,)
```

As you can see **the shape is not the same**.

Sklearn works with the (number,) format in general.
Consider reading the documentation of each sklearn algorithm/method and also check the examples that they have in their website.